# I cannot connect from adminer to postgresql

Tags: postgresql, docker-compose, adminer

I try to up postgresql and adminer via docker container. But from adminer I cannot enter  to postgresql with password and user I whote.

```
SQLSTATE[08006] [7] FATAL: password authentication failed for user "root"
```

I tried all.

```
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    build: .
    environment:
      - APACHE_RUN_USER=www-data
    volumes:
      - ./blog:/var/www/html/
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    working_dir: /var/www/html/
  db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: kisphp
      POSTGRES_USER: root
      POSTGRES_DB: kisphp
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - ./postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "6080:8080"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This docker-compose configuration works well.

Try recreating it from scratch:

1. Delete `./postgres` folder
2. `docker-compose stop`
3. `docker-compose down`
4. `docker-compose up -d`

Comment: but Why I have to use  ``` docker inspect container_name ``` to know the IP of postgres. Why I cannot set default localhost ?

Comment: No, you don't have to, adminer is deployed to the same docker-compose network, so you should use `db` as the host name to connect.

Comment: Thank you, Alex. I think the day then  I start to understand docker will come soon.

Comment: adminer connects well. But ````pgadmin4 could not translate host name "db" to address: Name does not resolve