# Docker Postgres and Adminer accept connection but doesn't work

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, adminer

On my rasperry pi 4 I've installed docker and docker-compose and now I'm tring to install and use Postgres and Adminer
following that https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres I've created docker-compose.yaml file as follow:

```
# Use postgres/example user/password credentials
version: '3.1'

services:

  db:
    image: postgres
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: postgres
    ports:
      - 5432:5432

  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
```

and i run it with

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yaml up -d
```

after that DB_1 starts and adminer too
but when i try connect to http://192.168.1.38:8080/ i can't reach it
even if i try connect to postgres through pgAdmin it's says
[image: terminal log]

> could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061) Is
> the server running on host "192.168.1.38" and accepting TCP/IP
> connections on port 5432?

however if i don't use docker-compose but just

```
docker run --name postgres -d --restart unless-stopped -p 5432:5432 -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=123456 -v ${PWD}/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data postgres
```

it's work through pgAdmin

do you know what i'm doing wrong?

UPDATE: seems the problem is with docker-compose because any kind of docker-compose.yml file block connection to it...

with a container with djgango i tried to start server and it's works but when i try reach page it seem bloccked too
[image: terminal with active django running]

[image: another terminal where i try connect to django server]

when i run docker-compose.yaml file ***docker-compose ps*** output is:
[image: docker-compose ps]

sudo netstat -tulpn screenshot
[image]

Answer (score 0):

PgAdmin can't reach 5432 ports because you don't expose it.
Like for Adminer you need to expose the Postgres port 5432 on your machine in your compose file.

```
version: '3.1'

services:

  db:
    image: postgres
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: postgres
    ports:
      - 5432:5432

  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
```

Comment: by default postgres uses port 5432 anyway even if i add     ports:
      - 5432:5432 to docker-compose.yaml the problem is the same ... seem docker-compose dosen't work... i can't reach it at http://192.168.1.30:8080 ....

Comment: Your initial error was "192.168.1.38" and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432? You need to expose it from your compose like your docker run command

Comment: Where the error  "192.168.1.38" and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432 comes from ?

Comment: the error come from pgAdmin when i try to connect after i used 
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yaml up -d
as i wrote if i don't use docker-compose but just i run the container with postgres image i'ts work fine....

i belive is a docker-compose problem... it's blocks any connection

Comment: What is your setup  PgAdmin on your computer and adminer + postgres on the raspberry ? what's the output of `docker-compose ps` ?

Comment: pgadmin have default setting for both test adn same username password and db .....postgress + admier is autogenerated by docker-compose.yaml 
docker-compose ps output is 
postgres_adminer_1   entrypoint.sh docker-php-e ...   Up      0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp,:::8080->8080/tcp
postgres_db_1        docker-entrypoint.sh postgres    Up      0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp,:::5432->5432/tcp

Comment: It's strange what's the result of `netstat -tulpn` ?

Comment: Added netstat -tulpn response as screehshot in main question
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktq2U.jpg

Comment: Can you run the command as root ? to be sure docker-compose don't bind ports.

Comment: ofcourse ! updated screenshot on question

Comment: Your postgres instance is not exposed but the adminer yes. You can check the logs of postgres with the command `docker-compose logs db`

Comment: You'd be horrified to find out how long I spent fruitlessly looking up various "solutions" to this exact problem, before I realised I had "MySQL" rather than "PostgreSQL" selected in the Adminer sign-in page. :(

Answer (score -1):

a little late to the party but what you need to do is figure out the IP address of the postgres container, and use that as your host.

Answer (score -1):

I just had the same issue than you. I think you probably solved it today but here is what I did:

```
docker-compose stop
docker-compose down

# It's probably overkill but we never know
docker system prune --all

docker-compose up
```

Then I went back to adminer, http://localhost:8080 and filled in the form and it worked.

I found the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56150504

FYI, here is my docker-compose file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    build:
      context: ./client
    environment:
      REACT_APP_API_URL: 'http://localhost:3000'
    ports:
      - "5173:5173"
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
    volumes:
      - ./client:/web
  api:
    build:
      context: ./server
    depends_on:
      - db
      - adminer
      - amqp
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
    volumes:
      - ./server:/api
  db:
    image: postgres:15.2
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: example
      POSTGRES_USER: example
      POSTGRES_DB: example
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
  adminer:
    image: adminer
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
  amqp:
    image: rabbitmq:3.11-management
    ports:
      - "5672:5672"
      - "15672:15672"
```